# How to get $(this) to work when called via jquery "on click" from an <li>

Tags: jquery, html-lists, onclicklistener, jquery-events

I have a dynamically created `<ul>` style menu and I want to find out which `<li>` was clicked.

After many attempts I am unable to get it to recognize which `<li>` was clicked. I have tried attaching the "on click" to each `<li>` and to the `<ul>`. I have also sat through two Javascript and a jQuery course at Lynda.com.

My best result is to get an empty alert box using Javascript. So after three frustrating days I have again come here for help.

```
<script>$(".qmli").on('click', function() { 
        alert($(this).text());
    });
</script>


<ul id="qm0" class="qmmc">
    <li><a class="qm-startopen qmparent" href="javascript:void(0)">Top menu</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="qmparent" href="javascript:void(0)">Plants</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>class='qmli" <a href="javascript:void(0)">Flowers</a></li>
                    <li>class='qmli" <a href="javascript:void(0)">Trees</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="qmparent" href="javascript:void(0)">Animals</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>class='qmli" <a href="javascript:void(0)">Lions</a></li>
                    <li>class='qmli" <a href="javascript:void(0)">Tigers</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
    <li>class='qmli" <a href="#">Overview</a></li>
    <li>class='qmli" <a href="javascript:void(0)">Publicity</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="qmclear">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Get rid of `href="javascript:void(0)"`.  It's bad practice.  Use `href="#"` instead.

2) What's up with `<li>class='qmli"`?  It should probably be `<li class="qmli">`.

3) You want to grab the `<a>` elements and you also should put your code inside a DOMReady function.  Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".qmli a").click(function(e) { 
        alert($(this).text());
        e.preventDefault(); //Essentially the equivalent of javascript:void(0); 
    });
});
```

And for best results that should be placed in the `<head>`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help preventDefault is something new I have learned.

Answer (score 1):

The markup you pasted is definitely not valid. I'm pretty sure any of the

```
<li>class='qmli" <a href="javascript:void(0)">Lions</a></li>
```

Should be something like

```
<li class="qmli"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Lions</a></li>
```

Then your code will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you for responding, the mismatched ' " was a typo when I was creating the question.

Answer (score 0):

**The Issue**

Fixing the classes and removing the `javascript:void(0)`'s is a good first step, however you also need to remember to wrap your jquery in a $(document).ready() function.(read the references I've attached down the bottom)

I have fixed up your html and your jquery and by fixing all the issues in your markup and code I have produced the results you were aiming to achieve.

- [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnAQa/1/)

---

**The Code**

html:

```
<ul id="qm0" class="qmmc">
    <li><a class="qm-startopen qmparent" href="#">Top menu</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="qmparent" href="#">Plants</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="qmli"><a href="#">Flowers</a></li>
                    <li class="qmli"><a href="#">Trees</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="qmparent" href="#">Animals</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="qmli"><a href="#">Lions</a></li>
                    <li class="qmli"> <a href="#">Tigers</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
    <li class="qmli"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
    <li class="qmli"> <a href="#">Publicity</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="qmclear">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>​
```

The jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".qmli").click(function() {

        alert($(this).text())
        preventDefault()
    });

});​
```

---

**References**

- [document.ready()](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready)
- [html classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

Comment: I appreciate the time you spent, I did not know about jsfiddle (which I will use often I am sure). Even with the changes it does not work in my web page. I must be something to do with the menu I am using. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: oh damn, well if you post your live site I could probably tell you why, as since this works in jsfiddle it is then an issue with something else in your code.

Comment: There is but it is not related to the on click so I have asked a new question. "How could a line of code in a javascript function cause another function to not be found?"

Comment: I have not posted a new question but I have found the problem, a missing " in an unrelated js function. Thank you again

Comment: haha yep that would do it, no worries; i'm glad you solved your issue c:

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes

1.Its `<li class='qmli'>` not `<li>class='qmli'`

2.You are putting your script on top of your mark up so u must wrap it in ready() handler

```
<script>
$(document).ready(){
$(".qmli").on('click', function() { 
        alert($(this).text());
    });
    });

</script>
```